# Printing an XML Holder in quotes hangs the Soapui/ReadyAPI

Tags: groovy, soapui, ready-api

Before trying the below code, **please save all your projects**

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)
def xmlHolder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("RequestStep#Response")

// Below line works fine
log.info xmlHolder

//Below code hangs the soapui/ready API
log.info "$xmlHolder"
```

why this happens printing a holder inside quotes hangs the system.

Whats the difference when printing an XML Holder inside and outside Quotes

Comment: Which free version are you using?

Comment: Soap version 5.4, Ready API version 2.5.0 , Both are the latest

Comment: May be you can report the issue with customer support if that is reproducible on ReadyAPI and any way that is not blocking you.

Comment: Is there any requirement you need to use that way only?

Comment: No, did it not reproduced on soapui for you ? No by mistake i put quotes.. and found that problem